# Linear Algebra: Prove matrices equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Please help me with the following problem

Given $m$ $n\times n$ matrices $A_1,A_2,...,A_m$, where $m>2^n$

Assuming that $A_i^2=O$ for all $i=1,2...,n$.

Prove that $A_1A_2...A_n=O$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Let's take $n = 2$. Set

$$ A_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, A_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then $A_1^2 = A_2^2 = 0$ and $A_1 A_2 A_1 = A_1$ so in particular we can form the product $A_1 A_2 A_1 A_2 A_1 = A_1$ which is non-zero.